# When turning on/off wifi, wifi is "soft blocked", any way to automatically run `rfkill unblock`?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, rfkill

So, on this Dell Inspiron 7520, which is hardware-certified for 12.04, when I use the function keys to turn off/on the wifi, the wifi will "turn on" but be soft blocked.

Running `rfkill unblock [interfacenumber]` does correctly unblock the device.

Is there a way for the system to automatically run `rfkill unblock [interfacenumber]` to remove the soft block when the wifi card is reenabled by the function keys?

---

My question here, though, is different than the other already-asked questions about soft blocks that I could find, so please do not mark it as a duplicate.  I am simply asking how to automate the unblocking process.

---

**The device is not a Broadcom card, and never will be.**  That does not appear to be the source of the soft block when the function keys are pressed and the wifi card comes back up.  From `lspci`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
```

---

Requested `xev | grep key` output from when I am using the hardware key(s) to turn off/on the wifi card:

```
% xev | grep key
    keys:  0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 248 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff95, XF86WLAN), same_screen YES,
```

Comment: Does `xev | grep key` give any output when you press the function key?

Comment: @Seth yes, `xev | grep key` does give output, and I've attached it.

Comment: Install xte (package name is `xautomation`) and try running `xte 'key 0x1008ff95'`. Does it toggle your wifi? Doesn't have to fix the soft block, but I want to see if that's the right key.

Comment: @Seth no it does not.

Comment: @Braiam I had this tagged for 12.04 because that's the version of Ubuntu I am using, is there a reason you're removing it and putting in `shortcut-keys` which is not applicable because I'm not trying to find a shortcut to do this but to automate this as part of the hardware switch process?  (rolled back until you provide ample justification for your change)